# Xpath to fetch attribute value

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am new to xpath/xquery and i have a task in hand.

The XML which i have is

```
<headers>

    <header name="dataType" value="6">

    </header>
    <header name="ActionType" value="6222"/>

</headers>
```

I need to fetch the value with the header name "dataType" and "ActionType".

i.e if the header name is "dataType" then the xpath should return "6" and if it is ""ActionType" then "6222".

Can anyone help me in this .

Thanks

Comment: I missed the main tag, it is something like this   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<headers>
   
    <header name="dataType" value="6">
       
    </header>
    <header name="ActionType" value="6222"/>
    
</headers>

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(@"header");

List<int> LISTdatatype = new List<int>();
List<int> LISTactiontype = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                if(elemList[i].Attributes["name"].Value == "dataType")
                    LISTdatatype.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["value"].Value);
                if(elemList[i].Attributes["name"].Value == "ActionType")
                    LISTactiontype.Add(elemList[i].Attributes["value"].Value);
            }
```

this is just a example to do it there are many ways to implement it, you dont have to use the Lists you could just use variables...

but i think this is the most easy way to solve your problem...

greetings

Comment: Thank you Florian, however i am trying to fetch the value in Xquery.So could you please provide the same in xpath.

Comment: Hi EveryOne, i was able to find the answer for the above in xpath data(//header[@name='dataType']/@value)

Comment: Nice, i was searching for it too ... but if anything is clear now, have a nice day =)